# Sort within group with linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, group-by

I have a list of objects. I want to order by Date, and then by TransParentType and then by TransType. Then I want to group by TransParentType and within each group place a specific item (if it exists) at the bottom of the group (withdrawal: specific).

Sample Data:

```
Date          TransParentType   TransType

2015/05/20    Purchase      investment
2015/05/20    Redemption    withdrawal: b
2015/05/20    Redemption    zz
2015/05/20    Redemption    withdrawal: a
2015/05/20    Redemption    withdrawal: specific
2015/05/20    Redemption    withdrawal: c   
2015/05/14    Purchase      investment
```

Expected Sorted Data:

```
Date          TransParentType   TransType

2015/05/14    Purchase      investment
2015/05/20    Purchase      investment
2015/05/20    Redemption    withdrawal: a
2015/05/20    Redemption    withdrawal: b
2015/05/20    Redemption    withdrawal: c
2015/05/20    Redemption    withdrawal: specific
2015/05/20    Redemption    zz
```

I'm trying to do something like this, without much success. The GroupBy does not maintain my sorted data. This is as far as i've gotten. Not sure if there is a way to move the specific item to the bottom of the group or if i have to do it manually...

```
results = results.OrderBy(r => r.Date).ThenBy(r=>r.TransParentType)
                             .ThenBy(r => r.TransType).ToList();

var grouped = results.GroupBy(g => g.TransParentType)...
```

Comment: This isn't really a job for GroupBy. GroupBy is used when you need to calculate aggregate values (total sum, total count, etc.) for certain groups of records. All you are really doing here is sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't see the need of the group by from your Expected sorted Data.

I would do

```
results = results.OrderBy(r => r.Date)
                 .ThenBy(r=>r.TransParentType)
                 //just add an order criterion, checking if TransType == the value that you want at the end
                 //as order by a boolean returns false results first, this will put "widthdrawal: specific" at the end
                 //this will only make a difference for the elements starting with "withdrawal:"
                 .ThenBy(r => r.TransType == "widthdrawal: specific")
                 //finally, order TransType for all elements
                 .ThenBy(r => r.TransType)
                 .ToList();
```

EDIT :

With the new specifications given, I see something (ugly) like that

```
        results = results
                     //order by date
                    .OrderBy(m => m.Date)
                    //order by transParentType
                    .ThenBy(m => m.TransParentType)
                     //order by the beginning of TransType (the part which may contain "withdrawal:"
                    .ThenBy(m => m.TransType.Substring(0, Math.Min(11, m.TransType.Length)))
                    .ThenBy(m => m.TransType == "withdrawal: specific")
                    .ThenBy(m => m.TransType);
```

Comment: This answer is slightly better than mine, since, as you point out, false comes before true when sorted. Nice. The comments are a nice touch as well. ;-)

Comment: @jeremcc well, probably slightly more performant, but I would say yours is more readable at first glance (order by boolean is not absolutely obvious)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus What happens if there is another item 2015/05/20    Redemption    zz - using the code above, it isn't placed at the end as it should be (z after w). The withdrawal: specific item is placed beneath the z item...

Comment: @newbie_86 of course it won't be placed at the end, because... that's not what you asked for ;) You should modify your question to be more specific (with other problematic cases), cause that's not clear in your question now.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Hmm, I did say it needs to be placed at the bottom of that group. Which is why I initially went down the grouping route. I'll update the data set in the question :)

Comment: @newbie_86 Well, maybe, but we all understood the same ;) So the problem is just if you have a `Redemption` >  `withdrawal: zz`, which should be placed before `withdrawal: specific` ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Nope, it should be placed after withdrawal:specific. So the final sorting should be sorting by TransType (i.e. zz after withdrawal), it's almost like saying that the withdrawal: specific shuffling should only happen within withdrawal transactions, but once that's done the normal asc sort order by TransType should kick in

Comment: @newbie_86 I meant a `withdrawal: zyzyz` not just a `zz`. Are we ok if we say that `withdrawal: zyzyz` should come before `withdrawal: specific`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes that's correct, withdrawal: specific must be after all withdrawal items

Comment: @newbie_86 ok. Edited answer should be better (?)

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes, and that's what we want (and that's why we have an `orderBy(r => r.TransType)` at the end, to discriminate all the -1, 0 and 1. Anyway, we don't need CompareTo, just the substring part. I edited.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thanks. What do you mean by "to discriminate all the -1, 0 and 1"?

Comment: @newbie_86 forget it, I edited, that's no more needed ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this will work:

```
results = results
    .OrderBy(r => r.Date)
    .ThenBy(r => r.TransParentType)
    .ThenBy(r => r.TransType == "withdrawal: specific" ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenBy(r => r.TransType).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you put `withdrawal: specific` after something like `unspecified transaction` etc.?

Comment: @JonHanna because that's excaclty what's asked ?

Comment: Right you are, I missed that in the bit about grouping.

Answer (score 0):

The output you show in your question doesn't group at all, and is simply:

```
results.OrderBy(r => r.TransParentType).ThenBy(r => r.Date).ThenBy(r => r.TransType == "withdrawal: specific").ThenBy(r => r.TransType);
```

If I try your code, I find that the GroupBy does indeed maintain the order, except for obviously having it split into two separate groups.

If `GroupBy` is indeed upsetting an order (though I can't see how) then you could use:

```
var groupedResults = results.GroupBy(r => r.Trans‎ParentType).Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(r => r.Date).ThenBy(r => r.TransType == "withdrawal: specific").ThenBy(r => r.TransType));
```

Which will give you an `IEnumerable<OrderedEnumerable<>>`, so you can `foreach` through each block and then `foreach` through those in order again, and so on. (Or an `IQueryable<IOrderedQueryable<>>` if done against a different linq source).